# Composable being rendered over and over

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Firebase login flow with one NavHost and when the user successfully logs in, I go to another NavHost with a BottomBar Navigation. This flow is working as expected. The problem I am running into is that the HomeScreen(after a successful login) is being rendered over and over again. I have a RootNavGraph that calls my authentication and made sure that is only being called once. Once that login is successful I am calling another NavHost for a bottom navigation.

```
            when (it) {
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                   // TODO("Add a forgot password section")
                    val context = LocalContext.current
                    Toast.makeText(context, it.exception.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(refLoader) {
                        top.linkTo(parent.top)
                        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                        end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    })
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(Graph.HOME)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I seem to be in an endless loop somehow where my HomeNavGraph is being called or the HomeScreen itself is being called.

```
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(navController: NavHostController, authViewModel: AuthViewModel) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, route = Graph.HOME,
    startDestination = BottomBarScreen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Search.route) {
            SearchScreen()
        }
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Home.route) {
            Log.d("HomeNavGraph", "HomeScreen is being called")
            HomeScreen(authViewModel = authViewModel)
        }
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Profile.route) {
            ProfileScreen(authViewModel = authViewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    authViewModel: AuthViewModel?,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = { BottomBar(navController = navController) }
    ) {
        Log.d("HomeNavGraph Call", "HomeNavGraph being called from HomeScreen")
            HomeNavGraph(navController = navController, authViewModel = authViewModel!!)
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    val screens = listOf(
        BottomBarScreen.Search,
        BottomBarScreen.Home,
        BottomBarScreen.Profile
    )
    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination
    
    val bottomBarDestination = screens.any { it.route == currentDestination?.route }
    if (bottomBarDestination) {
        BottomNavigation(
            backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
        ) {
            screens.forEach { screens ->
                AddItem(
                    screen = screens,
                    currentDestination = currentDestination,
                    navController = navController
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.AddItem(
    screen: BottomBarScreen,
    currentDestination: NavDestination?,
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    BottomNavigationItem(
        label = {
            Text(text = screen.title, color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant)
        },
        icon = {
            Icon(
                imageVector = screen.icon,
                contentDescription = "Navigation Icon",
                tint = MaterialTheme.colors.secondaryVariant
            )
        },
        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any {
            it.route == screen.route
        } == true,
        unselectedContentColor = LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = ContentAlpha.disabled),
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route) {
                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)
                launchSingleTop = true
            }
        }
    )
}
```

[image: HomeScreenLogs]

I am lost and have been debugging to figure out what is happening. I can see there is a loop but I have no clue where or why it would be happening as I am not looping through anything other than inside the HomeScreen itself to create the 3 items on the bottom bar.

Comment: In `HomeNavGraph()` you're calling `HomeScreen()` which in turn calls `HomeNavGraph()` which calls `HomeScreen()` which calls `HomeNavGraph()`... Well I think you got the point :)

Comment: @m0skit0 Wow, I did not even see that. Thank you for calling that out. I was able to add a ContentScreen and call that for each composable into the HomeNavGraph vs calling the HomeScreen over and over again. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @m0skit0 I was able to see I need to create a composable for the HomeNavGraph to call that would render content for each view of the bottomNavigation.

I created

```
@Composable
fun ScreenContent(name: String, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.clickable { onClick() },
            text = name,
            fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h3.fontSize,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
    }
}
```

Called these within the HomeNavGraph as so

```
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(navController: NavHostController, authViewModel: AuthViewModel) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController, route = Graph.HOME,
        startDestination = BottomBarScreen.Home.route
    ) {
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Search.route) {
            ScreenContent(
                name = BottomBarScreen.Search.route,
                onClick = {}
            )
        }
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Home.route) {
            ScreenContent(
                name = BottomBarScreen.Home.route,
                onClick = {}
            )
        }
        composable(route = BottomBarScreen.Profile.route) {
            ScreenContent(
                name = BottomBarScreen.Profile.route,
                onClick = {}
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This displayed each screen of the bottom navigation as expected and stopped the loop of calling HomeScreen which called HomNavGraph which called HomeScreen, etc.